# gcc - generating code for a function without frames or surrounding

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

### Context

Linux 64 bits.
gcc 5.1

I compile a code with `gcc -O3 -march=native FLAGS -c myapp.c`
Note the presence of the -c switch.

Say that file has one function.

The goal : get the generated code and put it in a jit compiler. Keeping the maximum optimizations is essential here.

I want **machine code** ready to be embedded & executed in my main program.

Libgccjit is not mature enough to be used yet (and I don't like the interface anyway)

### Question

Is there an option to ONLY get the code gcc generated for a function without having to resort to an external parser to throw away the frames and other assembly informations not directly related to the code ?

Example with a stupid code:

```
    .cstring
LC0:
    .ascii "ok\0"
    .section __TEXT,__text_cold,regular,pure_instructions
LCOLDB1:
    .text
LHOTB1:
    .align 4,0x90
    .globl __Z4flopi
__Z4flopi:
LFB4:
    pushq   %rbp
LCFI0:
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    $69, %ebp
    pushq   %rbx
LCFI1:
    leal    71(%rdi), %ebx
    leaq    LC0(%rip), %rdi
    subq    $8, %rsp
LCFI2:
    cmpl    $56, %ebx
    cmovne  %eax, %ebp
    call    _puts
    addq    $8, %rsp
LCFI3:
    leal    0(%rbp,%rbx), %eax
    popq    %rbx
LCFI4:
    popq    %rbp
LCFI5:
    ret
LFE4:
    .section __TEXT,__text_cold,regular,pure_instructions
LCOLDE1:
    .text
LHOTE1:
    .section __TEXT,__eh_frame,coalesced,no_toc+strip_static_syms+live_support
EH_frame1:
    .set L$set$0,LECIE1-LSCIE1
    .long L$set$0
LSCIE1:
    .long   0
    .byte   0x1
    .ascii "zR\0"
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x78
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0xc
    .byte   0x7
    .byte   0x8
    .byte   0x90
    .byte   0x1
    .align 3
LECIE1:
LSFDE1:
    .set L$set$1,LEFDE1-LASFDE1
    .long L$set$1
LASFDE1:
    .long   LASFDE1-EH_frame1
    .quad   LFB4-.
    .set L$set$2,LFE4-LFB4
    .quad L$set$2
    .byte   0
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$3,LCFI0-LFB4
    .long L$set$3
    .byte   0xe
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0x86
    .byte   0x2
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$4,LCFI1-LCFI0
    .long L$set$4
    .byte   0xe
    .byte   0x18
    .byte   0x83
    .byte   0x3
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$5,LCFI2-LCFI1
    .long L$set$5
    .byte   0xe
    .byte   0x20
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$6,LCFI3-LCFI2
    .long L$set$6
    .byte   0xe
    .byte   0x18
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$7,LCFI4-LCFI3
    .long L$set$7
    .byte   0xe
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$8,LCFI5-LCFI4
    .long L$set$8
    .byte   0xe
    .byte   0x8
    .align 3
LEFDE1:
    .constructor
    .destructor
    .align 1
    .subsections_via_symbols
```

to

```
LC0:
    .ascii "ok\0"
__Z4flopi:
    pushq   %rbp
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    $69, %ebp
    pushq   %rbx
    leal    71(%rdi), %ebx
    leaq    LC0(%rip), %rdi
    subq    $8, %rsp
    cmpl    $56, %ebx
    cmovne  %eax, %ebp
    call    _puts
    addq    $8, %rsp
    leal    0(%rbp,%rbx), %eax
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

Don't bother with the fact that linkers/loaders may not like it, mine know what to do with it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to get an assembly file or machine code?

Comment: @zch: good question I forgot to be explicit! Machine code. +1

Comment: I currently have to parse and clean the assembly output and then i convert it to obj code. This process is quite heavy though. If I could have gcc clean it already, it would be easier.. If it could as well make machine code, it would be wonderful.. But gcc may complain because of the former cleaning.. So gcc -> machine code is not vital.

Comment: In such a case you would need to use a format that handles symbols (`__Z4flopi:`) and probably relocations, if your code need to refer to some external symbols. So you would probably need code for handling ELF files and for applying relocations.

Comment: Absolutely. This is already managed and it is not always trivial. But we control the whole process so.. I guess i am out of luck, gcc is not made for it. I am kind of going against it here..

Comment: there are parameters available to gcc to tell it to not gen stack frames.  There are parameters available to gcc to tell it to output the assembled source file.  You can get all the details here: <https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.4/gcc_3.html>

Comment: @user3629249: could you expand on this, I did not find the options that help in my regard on your page (that I happen to have already read). You mean stack frame altogether or frame pointer ?